# I'd like to get a job in the medical (career or profession)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, difference, comparison

What's the correct sentence?

> I'd like to get a job in the medical career.

or

> I'd like to get a job in the medical profession.

Comment: I would suggest something like medical branch/ medical sector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *career* means a *job field* over a long period of time, you can't really say *job in a career*.
However,

> I'd like to get a job in the **medical profession**.

is fine. You would have a *job* in a *job field/profession*.

You could also say:

> I'd like to **have** a **career** in the medical profession.

*have* would be used since it is a condition over a period of time, while *get* refers to starting something.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd like to add that ___the_ medical profession__ is that of "doctor"; though I am a medical professional, you would not say of me that I work in "the medical profession" because I am not a physician.  Since we do not speak of "getting a job in doctoring" the way we do "getting a job in sales", while the first example is fine English, it's not actually something a native speaker would say.  We might say, "...a job in the medical field" or "...a job in __a__ medical field" or "...a job in the medical sector" or even "...a job in healthcare".

Comment: @Codeswitcher Well I was not trying to get quite that detailed, and the OP did not state what actual job was meant. But *a medical profession* does not have to be a doctor. In any case, more common phrases nowadays are *healthcare industry* or *healthcare careers*, which refer to any healthcare related occupation.

Comment: We typically say in AmE that  someone "wants to *enter* the medical profession". (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(to+enter+the+medical+profession)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28to%20enter%20the%20medical%20profession%29%3B%2Cc0)